# how to create a string like regex

Tags: c#

i am new in C# language, i am trying to create a new desktop app.

but i am confuse to create a string like this..

```
private string getResult(int x){
    string results = "";

    return results  
}
```

so when i use `getResult(1)`, it will return `0001`

if i use `getResults(111)`, it will return `0111`

if i use `getResults(10)`, it will return `0010`.

something like this, i am confuse to create a string like this.

Comment: What is the desired outcome for  `x = -123456`, please?

Comment: `private void string` does not work! you need to remove the `void` if you want to return a value and make it compileable

Comment: @DmitryBychenko in my case, its impossible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simple use `ToString` with parameter:

```
private string getResult(int x)
{
    return x.ToString("0000"); 
}
```

from @Dmitry Bychenko :

You can also use `"D4"` as parameter instead of `"0000"` with same results.

This solution also works with negative numbers instead of `PadLeft` method.

Comment: `"D4"` (i.e. **4** digits) is an alternative format string

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using a Regex and still get the same result: you can use `PadLeft` like this:

```
results.PadLeft(4, '0');
```

So your entire method would look like:

```
private string getResult(int x)
{
    return x.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
}
```

Comment: Be carerul with *negative numbers*: `x = -1` will result `"00-1"`